# Access Volumio via No-IP

Tags: networking, audio, remote

I just installed Volumio on my RPI and I was able to access it inside my network by using its IP address.

Now I want to achieve something else. I want to access the musics on my external HD on Volumio from outside my network using an authentication. So I was thinking if it's possible to use No-IP to achieve that.

I know that I will have to install No-IP client on my raspberry. If its possible to acccess it via No-IP how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No-IP just gives your public IP address an easy-to-access domain name, via No-IP's servers. You should be able to access Volumio simply as normal, just connecting to the Pi with the domain name you aquire from No-IP. You'll have to register with them and then set up your Pi accordingly

Comment: I figured out that if i open a port on my router and redirect the requests to this port for my RPI ip might work.

Comment: Both the question and the answer seems to be ... wrong. It would be plain bad if a newbie found this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to do that by installing no ip client on my Raspberry PI and then in my router I redirected a specific port to my Raspberry PI IP address.

In No-IP server I added a new host with a redirect to a port, setting my public IP address and the port I enabled for my Raspberry PI on my router.

This way when I access my No-IP outside my network, it will call my public IP address and redirect to my raspberry pi based on the opened port and it shows the Volumio web interface.

Of course you will need a firewall and an intrusion detection system.